# How can i access a css attribute from a .load()'ed page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load an entire website in to my website. I have been able to do this with `$(#preview).load("index.php")` into my `<div id="preview"></div>`. What i have troubles accessing here is the background image which is a property of body. I tried making a div tag with a background-image attribute but when i removed the image from my body tag it didnt behave like i wanted to (was not filling the entire space).

My question is this. **How can i access something from index.php that can let me either preview the site correctly or copy the attribute from somewhere into the preview background-image attribute?**

my code now looks like this, after some extensive try-and-error (more like error-and-error and its getting more and more messy)

```
    $(document).ready(
        function() {    
            $("#check").click(
                function() {
                    var bgd;
                    $("#preview").load("index.php", 
                        function () {
                            bgd = $("#bg").css("background-image");
                        }
                    );
                    $("#preview").style.backgroundImage(bgd);
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

Where bg is the id of the div which works as a "substitute" body tag in index.php (aka with the same attributes as body)

Im either far from it, or ridiculously close. Thanks for every piece of advice i can get.

Comment: `style` and `backgroundImage` is not a jQuery method.. you should try `.css('background-image',bgd)`

Comment: [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)'s callback sends the response data as the first parameter, you'll want to grab that and inject it into your document before trying to modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems here. One with how you're accessing style properties and the other has to do with the asynchronous behavior of `load()`.

#### Style problem

You'll need to use `$("#preview").css('background-image',bgd)`.  The first method you were using could still be kept around by accessing the non-jQuery wrapped element, like so:

```
$("#preview")[0].style.backgroundImage(bgd);
```

#### Async problem

The second issue is that .load() is an asynchronous call that *returns immediately*.  The next line of code gets executed and `bdg` is (most likely) still undefined.  Then when `load()` completes, the success handler gets executed and `bdg` gets set to the background of the loaded page, but it's too late!

Moving the `$("#preview").css('background-image',bgd)` into the success handler will rectify that problem:

```
   $(document).ready(
        function() {    
            $("#check").click(
                function() {
                    var bgd;
                    $("#preview").load("index.php", 
                        function () {
                            bgd = $("#bg").css("background-image");
                            $("#preview").css('background-image',bgd);
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this so good to me and made it easy to understand while still using my own code :) +1 to Jonathan F

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(document).ready(
        function() {    
            $("#check").click(
                function() {
                    $.ajax({
                             url: 'index.php',
                             success: function(data){
                                 data = $('data').html();
                                 $('#preview').html(data);
                                 bg = $('data').find('#bg').css('background-image');
                                 $('#preview').css('background-image',bg);
                             }
                        });

                }
            );
        }
    );
```

Comment: .load() is asynchronous... move it into the success handler

Comment: You can still use load here.  It helps you from having to parse and add the data to the target element by hand.

Comment: ow, didnt think about ajax. Tbh i dont even know what ajax do, i just read a bit up on jquery while skipping ajax on w3schools xD